# How to create multiple flow files from one incoming flow files in nifi using ExecuteScript with python

Tags: python, apache-nifi, execute-script, flowfile

Running locally, this works exactly how I want it to (has one incoming flow file with many different codes in position 7-10 and outputs 1 file per unique code)  For example if record 1-5 has 1234 in positions 7-10, and record 6 has 2345 in position 7-10, and record 7 has 1234 in positions 7-10, then there would be one file called 1234_file.txt with rows 1-5 and 7 and a second file 2345_file.txt would have row 6 from the input file:

```
f = open("test_comp.txt", "r")
for x in f:
    comp = x[6:10]
    print(comp)
    n = open(comp+"_file.txt","a")
    n.write(x)
    n.close()
f.close()
```

In nifi, I am trying this:

```
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
        pass
  def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    f = open(inputStream, 'r')
    for x in f:
        comp = x[6:10]
        print("comp: ",comp)
        newFile = open(comp+"_file.txt","a")
        newFile.write(x)


flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback())
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
session.commit()
```

It seems to be getting the input and correctly storing comp as position 7-10 as expected, but I'm not getting multiple flow files out (for each unique string in x[6:10].  And the flow file coming out is 1 zero byte file.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing??

Answer (score 2):

You are writing directly to files on your file system rather than *flowfiles* which are objects within the NiFi ecosystem. I'd suggest reading the [Apache NiFi Developer's Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#split-content-one-to-many) for context around those patterns and looking at some [Python ExecuteScript examples](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/03/executescript-json-to-json-revisited_14.html) to see the relevant Python code.

Rather than write a single flowfile out, you'll need to create multiple flowfile objects, map the data to them, and then transfer *all* of them to the respective relationship.

Is there a reason you need to use custom Python code to do this rather than the [`SplitRecord`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitRecord/index.html) and/or [`PartitionRecord`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PartitionRecord/index.html) processors? I think `PartitionRecord` would solve the problem you've described very easily.

Comment: Thanks, I will read the articles you suggested.

As for, PartitionRecord, what controller service would work since my file is simply a flat file (not csv)?

Comment: Can you provide some sample lines? The CSVReader can be configured to parse many delimited files even if they're not commas or tabs or pipes

Comment: I agree with Matt, if the incoming data is "flat", the `CSVReader` is probably the best solution using a configurable delimiter. If none of the OOTB controller services work for you, there is a `Scripted` option as well.

Comment: 470120123829       2000004590}00000051 3212           057                                                                     YVKB 20125  00          999999999999901    HG04070316               123 Main street, US 99999
470220123729       2000091230}00000051 2012           056                                                                     Y2HF 27258  00          999999999999901    HG04070316               123 Main street, US 99999

Comment: There are two sample lines.  Both of those are intended to end up in different flow files because one has 1238 in position 7-10 and the other has 1237 in position 7-10.